# Script javascript not found OR require not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, require

I'm following NodeJS tutorials for few days and trying to do some tests as practicing.
Here is a problem I don't understand, maybe somebody can help me about it :)

My files structure looks like this (I don't mention folders/files that don't concern this problem) :

```
- app.js
- views
--- users.ejs
--- partials
------ header.ejs
------ footer.ejs
- utils
--- script.js
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const myUsers = ["toto", "tutu", "titi"]

app.set("view engine","ejs")
app.use('/utils', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/utils' )))

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    res.render("users")
})

app.listen(port)

module.exports = {myUsers};
```

**users.ejs**

```
<%- include ('partials/header'); -%>
<p id="usr">Users are : </p>
<script type="module" src="../utils/script.js"></script>
<%- include ('partials/footer'); -%>
```

**script.js**

```
const myApp = require("../app")

let p_users = document.getElementById("usr");

p_users.innerHTML += myApp.myUsers
```

When I get to http://localhost:3000/users, I have a "ReferenceError: require is not defined" error.

And if I put my script.js at the root of my structure (with app.js) and change my users.ejs file with the new path for my script

```
<script type="module" src="../script.js"></script>
```

I have a "GET http://localhost:3000/js.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" whereas in VSCode, a Ctrl+click on "../script.js" open my script.js file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `const myApp = require("../app")`  you can't include Node.js specific code in the browser.   But you have created a route `app.get("/users",`,  so from the browser you will want to use `fetch` to get the users.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Keith Thank you for your answer.
Sorry, but what do you mean by "from the browser" ?
Actually, is it not possible to have a JS file that have access to variable (or const) from my app.js AND to my html document (so I can display the content of this variable with .innerHtml) ?